# how to remove square brackets from user agent header?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, user-agent

The following code changes the user-agent:

```
        
        headers = randint(0, 1)
        with open('headers.csv', 'r') as fd:
            reader = csv.reader(fd)
            reader = list(reader)
            driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {
                                    "userAgent": str(reader[headers])})
```

The headers csv file contains only two headers for testing purposes:
headers.csv:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36
```

When going to 'https://amiunique.org/fp' on my normal browser, the user agent header is normal.
[normal browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cHu0.png)

And of when using selenium chrome driver using the above user-agent changing code, this is the result:
[selenium chromedriver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXVdq.png)

I am assuming that the `[]` parenthesizing the user-agent header is what is causing me to be detected. how do I get rid of the `[]` from the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your item (reader[headers]) is a list itself. Use

```
"userAgent": ''.join(reader[headers])
```

instead.

Comment: thank you this worked perfectly. could you elaborate a bit on the variable names issue?

Comment: I edited the answer. It's not really an issue, but would make the code easier to read. You're actually selecting a single user agent header from that file, and 'headers' is actually an integer index, so 'headers' doesn't quite describe what the variable contains.

Comment: I would use something like 'idx = randint(...)', 'headers = list(reader)', 'user_agent = headers[idx]'

Comment: ah thanks. funnily enough its code i copied from stackoverflow lol. also, even thought the [] are gone, it is still saying the user agent is unique even though its copied and pasted from my normal browser into the csv file.